Does the PCT application follow a different format than the non-provisional of the USPO?
If I have a non-provisional application ready to file with the USPTO, do I need to change anything about it to convert it to a PCT application?

This is often done. However, PCT applications have stricter formatting requirements than non provisionals.
The paper size must be A4, the drawings need to be to a higher standard, for example.
Besides formatting you need to think about the requirements of whatever jurisdiction you might  decide to pursue. For example the EPO is very strict about claiming combinations of features that are not explicitly described in the specification.
You can find the formatting requirements in the MPEP section 18.

The question is pretty clearly in regards to the format of the PCT with respect to a non-provisional application.

Thanks - I changed the answer.
